# Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: fabric.Canvas is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, exception, canvas, meteor, fabricjs

I am developing a `fabric.js` application via `meteor`. I have included the file http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js in the project and I try to define a simple canvas as follows,

```
Template.formatter.rendered = function () {

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabriccanvas'); //<-- error Line
    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));

    canvas.selectionColor = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
    canvas.selectionBorderColor = 'red';
    canvas.selectionLineWidth = 5;


}
```

But I get the error `Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: fabric.Canvas is not a constructor`. I am very new to these environments and will really appreciate any help from you experts to solve this :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that you have the script into the `/client/compatibility`

> This folder is for compatibility JavaScript libraries that rely on
>   variables declared with var at the top level being exported as
>   globals. Files in this directory are executed without being wrapped in
>   a new variable scope. These files are executed before other
>   client-side JavaScript files.

from [doc meteor structuringyourapp](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I tried both your suggestions. its not a typo as this solution works fine in jsfiddle. and after remove the `new` keyword I get the error `Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: fabric.Canvas is not a function`

Comment: Where did you put the script? on the /lib folder?

Comment: or put them into this folder `client/compatibility`

Comment: Hi.. that did the trick! if you could update the answer I could mark it. I had it in the `lib` folder. May I know why it needs to be in `client/compatibility` folder?